# Am I right that WiX Library Project not suitable to share Component(s) Definitions (and there are no way to parametrize Guid)?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, wix

The WiX Component mostly allways should have a **Guid** attribute, so if I want to move the component's **definition** e.g. compnent with of iis:WebAppPool and iis:WebVirtualDir (or another sample - the component that content Log folder with permissions) into the **WiX Library Project** I will not have a possibility to reuse those definitions with different guids...  For me it is a problems, I want to share definition for defining diferent components (with different guids)!

And there are no way to do something around.

I have tried to setup guid through property like

```
<Component Name="cmpKuku" Guid="[cmpGUID]" />
```

but this doesn't work => component's GUID does not accept parameters. May be there are other ways how to parametrize component's guids? Of coursse parametrizing through preprocessor varibles doesn't work also in case of Wix Library Project.

Guid="*" is calculable, but as I understand it depends only on content of component not on parents, product, features? It would be good for me if, in case of referencing in different feature/product,  wix calculates different guids for * ...

*x) Do we have other way to share iis:WebVirtualPage and iis:WebAppPool definitions, without framed component?*

Answer (score 4):

I have read the exact same post. The reason Rob Mensching says that is that you could not use wixlibs with other tools because they are wix-specific.
However, either wixlibs and merge modules are very similar (although wixlibs are a better/faster and newer choice).
So, to answer your question, yes, you can use wixlibs for containing the components because, as I mentioned above, they are similar to merge modules. Essentially, a single shared component must have the same GUID during its all lifetime and windows installer knows how to keep track of them.

so, for example, let's say you have an a.wixlib containing some component. Then you create two separate installers, b.msi and c.msi, referencing the same wixlib and install them. The Windows installer sets the component's reference count to 2.
Later you decide to uninstall b.msi. Windows installer decreases the component's reference count to 1 but does not yet uninstall it. The reason is that wixlibs, just like merge modules are used for shared components (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa369820(v=vs.85).aspx). So, after you uninstall the c.msi, only the component is removed.

One more thing. You could generate GUID during linking by placing guid="*" attribute. I am generally against it but it is valid.

Edit: to avoid misleading people about asterisks, using them is not a bad practice because that might be the simplest way to build a product prepared for upgrading, since for upgrades you need to generate a new GUID anyway. So, if there are no additional complexities in the build, using asterisks might be just fine.

Comment: When you use `guid="*"` for a component, it is not generated, but calculated. See [How To: Generate a GUID](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/generate_guids.htm) or [Component Element](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/wix_xsd_component.htm).

Comment: That stable guid is what I meant. It will be the same each time the project is build. `guid="*"` on other places means a new guid is generated each time the project is build. I just meant to clarify that.

Comment: Thank you Paulius, but what if I need different scenario: "unstable gui" (actually that what I want) that means changeable with each "wix library referencing" case ?  For example log folder definition, with all permissions... Each my app contains the same log folder component definition except guid, and the fact that log folders are located in different direcotries... Therefore I need somehow parametrize the guid. In one app use one guid, in other use second guid. How?

Comment: @Wintel : that * brings me a hope. could you share the knowledge about how guid is _calculated_ =* ? May be the calculation of component guids depends on parents? Product and Feature?  It would be perfect.

Comment: A more graphical example would be welcome but this situation reminds me of something I have seen before. You could use an external script to place pre-generated GUIDs in components before the build. So, for example, you may have two sets of GUIDs pre-generated and and run the script before the build with specific parameter, which would insert them as needed. Although in that case the whole "shared components" thing would not make sense.